# Cakephp 2.1 Form Error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have just started using cakePHP 2.1. After submiting a form. If there is a validation error how to check the params whether there is an error ?

Before we used to do something like

```
$this->data['params'];
```

Comment: By default, the validation errors should appear below each form input that was invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you are saving the data in Form submit and you have validations defined on that Model, the data will be saved only when the call to `Model->save()` returns true. In that case  most probably you have validations error. The way you can specifically check is to check Model's validationErrors proprty.

In your controller

```
    if(!$this->Model->save($data)) {
         if(!empty($this->Model->validationErrors)) {
             //save failed due to validation errors
             debug($this->Model->validationErrors);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Perk has posted some excellent videos in Youtube for CakePHP. You can watch one of those explains how can do an AJAX validation with CakePHP and jQuery.

Please watch it [Cakephp Ajax Tutorial - Using Cakephp's Js Helper and jQuery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ71psonQx0)
It may be helpful for you.